# scipy.signal.fftconvolve doesn't give the required results

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I have a question regarding python's `fftconvolve`. In my current research I've been required to calculate some convolution between two functions. To do so I'm calculating it using fourier transform (which I used `numpy.fft` and normalize it) . The thing is that if I want to compare it using `fftconvolve` package, it fails to give the correct results. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve , convolve 

def FFT(array , sign):
  if sign==1:
    return np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(np.fft.fftshift(array))) * dw / (2.0 * np.pi)
  elif sign==-1:
    return np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fftshift(array))) * dt * len(array)


def convolve_arrays(array1,array2,sign):
  sign = int(sign)
  temp1 = FFT(array1 , sign,)
  temp2 = FFT(array2 , sign,)
  temp3 = np.multiply(temp1 , temp2)
  return  FFT(temp3 , -1 * sign) / (2. * np.pi) 

""" EXAMPLE """ 

dt    = .1
N     = 2**17
t_max = N * dt / 2
time  = dt * np.arange(-N / 2 , N / 2 , 1)

dw    = 2. * np.pi / (N * dt)
w_max = N * dw / 2.
w     = dw * np.arange(-N / 2 , N / 2 , 1)

eta_fourier = 1e-10




Gamma   = 1.
epsilon = .5
omega   = .5


G    = zeros(N , complex)
G[:] = 1. / (w[:] - epsilon + 1j * eta_fourier)

D    = zeros(N , complex)
D[:] = 1. / (w[:] - omega + 1j * eta_fourier) - 1. / (w[:] + omega + 1j * eta_fourier)

H    = convolve_arrays(D , G , 1)     
J    = fftconvolve(D , G , mode = 'same') * np.pi  / (2. * N)
```

If you plot the real/imaginary part of `H`, `J` you'll see a shift in the `w` axes and also I had to multiply the `J`'s results in order to get somehow close (but still not) to the correct results.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Go and take a look at [`scipy.fftconvolve`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L153) and observe that the algorithm has none of your strange fft shifts or scalings. What are you trying to achieve with the `FFT` function?

Answer (score 7):

**Boundary conditions are important when you compute convolutions.**

When you convolve two signals, the edges of the result depend on what values you assume *outside* the edges of the inputs. [`fftconvolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html) computes convolution assuming zero-padded boundaries.

Take a look at the [source code of fftconvolve](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.13.0/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L153). Notice the shenanigans they go through to achieve zero-padded boundary conditions, in particular, these lines:

```
size = s1 + s2 - 1
```

...

```
fsize = 2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(size)).astype(int) #For speed; often suboptimal!
fslice = tuple([slice(0, int(sz)) for sz in size])
```

...

```
ret = ifftn(fftn(in1, fsize) * fftn(in2, fsize))[fslice].copy()
```

...

```
return _centered(ret, s1) #strips off padding
```

This is good stuff! It's probably worth reading `fftconvolve`'s code carefully, and a good education if you want to understand Fourier-based convolution.

**Brief sketch**

The forward FFT zero-pads each signal to prevent periodic boundary conditions:

```
a = np.array([3, 4, 5])
b = np.fft.ifftn(np.fft.fftn(a, (5,))).real
print b #[ 3.  4.  5.  0.  0.]
```

the inverse FFT of the product of the forward FFTs gives a padded result:

```
a = np.array([3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([0., 0.9, 0.1])
b = np.fft.ifftn(np.fft.fftn(a, (5,))*
                 np.fft.fftn(b, (5,))
                 ).real
print b #[ 0.   2.7  3.9  4.9  0.5]
```

and the `_centered` function strips off the extra padding pixels at the end (assuming you use the `mode='same'` option).

Comment: It looks like newer versions of fftconvolve [do a better job choosing how much to pad to get fast FFT computations](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L349)